# Why I can import a Java class but I cannot refer it in Unit Test?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am not quite familiar with Java's compile and run tricks. I just met a strange problem that I can import a java class but I cannot refer it in Unit Test:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column; 
...
    @Test
    public void getDisaggregationResultTest() {
        Column nationalForecast = functions.lit(10);         
    }
```

This is a Spark codes in Java. 'Column' can be referred without problem, but 'functions' is complained to be 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError'. Does anybody have comments on this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Possibly because `functions` is not an actual class or method, just a package name.  EDIT: no, `functions` is a class, some bright spark just decided to use a lower case name instead of following the conventions.  Seriously Apache, wtf?

Comment: So I got nothing.  Possibly your installation is damaged and the class `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` doesn't appear in your class path (or in the install directory).  Suggest you look at it from that angle.  Does this class work in another project?  Is the class path the same for both projects?  Make sure you don't have two separate installations, one of which is faulty.

Comment: @markspace spark is written in scala. That's why.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Then is it possible to do Unit Test in Spark of Java if I want to make full use of Spark libraries in my Unit Test case?

Comment: @HouZhe Yes. I was just explaining **why** `functions` is a class written in lower case letters. It's actually written in scala. You can still invoke it from Java.